# No such file or directory - config/environment.rb phusion passenger apache centos 6.3 rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, centos, passenger

I am trying to allow sub urls on my apache/rails/phusion passenger install so that I can have php files at the top level and then rails apps in sub directories like blog for example:

I've followed the documentation here: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri

here is my httpd.conf virtual host entry:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xx.xx.xx.xx
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory /var/www/html>
Allow from all
</Directory>
RailsBaseURI /blog
<Directory /var/www/html/blog>   
Options -MultiViews               
</Directory>   
</VirtualHost>
```

the apache user owns /var/www/html and here is my shortcut link: 
http://d.pr/i/aLkP made with the ln command

and here is the error: http://d.pr/i/M3r4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apache group must also be able to read and execute the the config and public folders and all *parent* folders. Try changing the permissions and restarting apache.

Your symlink should have the same name as the suburl, so your symlink should be named "blog". It looks like it's named "public" right now. You may want to place your symlinks in a separate folder in your `www` directory.

Comment: Yes, but in this case, /var would also have to be given group read/execute for `apache`. Also check /var/www/html/, var/www/html/blog, and the parent directories to your app + railsapp/config, and railsapp/public.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying to install Redmine. To solve this problem I had to change the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` and specify the `PassengerAppRoot`:

```
<Directory /var/www/redmine>
    RailsBaseURI /redmine
    PassengerAppRoot /var/lib/redmine
    PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
</Directory>
```

I also modified the `/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf` and specified the  `PassengerDefaultUser`.

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr
  PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
  PassengerDefaultUser www-data
</IfModule>
```